# How to only show links to an admin in Rails manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got this helper method

```
>def admin?
>@user.email == "X@gmail.com"
>end
```

And this user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^(|(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$/i

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I try to access this line of code

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) if admin? %>

It says that there is an undefined method email. I want only myself to be able to edit and make blog posts, so this is the method I'm going with. I'm open to any suggestions that are more efficient, but want to avoid using gems like cancan for admin and such as I want to try to build this from scratch.

Much thanks!!

Comment: Are you calling the `authenticate` method anywhere?  Where is the instance variable `@user` used in the helper defined?  Also, I think it's beneficial to keep the helpers free of instance variables.

Comment: You could also use rolify (but only if you want more roles... for just the admin part @FCStrike's answer is more than enough). Wow. Such gratitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add an admin column to your User model where true = admin and false = not. That way you won't have to hard code who's an admin in the model.

The code you currently have won't do what you want it to do by the way. @user is the user returned when you're on a given page. You want to see if the signed in user is an admin, not @user (assuming you're following normal rails conventions).

I would just:

```
rails g migration AddAdminToUsers admin:boolean
```

Then in the model:

```
def admin?
  self.admin
end
```

Then in the view:

```
<%= your code here if current_user.admin? %>
```

You'll have to retrieve your current_user, but without seeing your code you'll have to do that yourself.

Edit: And initialize the User to have admin = false on create.

Comment: Thanks! And how would I set a particular user to admin on create?

Comment: If you were wondering how to set admin = false on create, you'd simply use a callback. If you were wondering how to set other people to admin status, I wouldn't do it on create - on create set admin = false, and then have a separate page where admins (or just you) can set other people as admins as well. A simple implementation would be to have an option on the Users index which promotes people to admin status, which is only visible to admins. For added security in the controller's update action, you can see if the admin parameter is being passed through params[:user][:admin] != @user.admin

Comment: If that evaluates to true, simply throw an error or redirect the user to the home page or something. You could of course implement this system anywhere, the User show page is another good candidate.